# Explicit construction of integrals of motion in 1d XXZ model for few sites

Tags: condensed-matter, many-body, integrable-systems, integrals-of-motion

I was studying the algebraic Bethe ansatz for the spin-1/2 XXZ model. In the end one ends up with $2^L$ integrals of motion $Q_k$ that commute with the Hamiltonian, (https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.125.090602) and (https://doi.org/10.1088/1751-8121/ac0961).

However the way they are defined is very dense, and I just wanted to know if the integrals of motions are written down explicitly anywhere, at least for a new sites, $n=2,3,4$, etc, in terms of the Pauli/spin matrices. There should be (4, 8, 16) of them, so in principle you should be able to write them down.

I guess I wanted to see if for the few site integrals of motion you can start to see that they are somehow local, and independent from the projectors $\lvert n \rangle \langle n \rvert$.

Comment: Does the question, my answer and the comments at https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/669182/ help?

Comment: Hi Jules, thanks for the reply. I already knew that Q_1 is the magnetisation, and Q_2 is the Hamiltonian, but I was hoping to find at least Q_3, the nontrivial conserved quantity. I went through your notes but couldn't find an explicit construction of Q_3. Is it possible to write it down for the XXZ model?

Comment: The next charge can be e.g. found in Exercise 2.7 of the book C. Gómez, M. Ruiz-Altaba, and G. Sierra, "Quantum Groups in Two-Dimensional Physics" (Cambridge University Press, 1996)

Comment: (I'm just talking about the log derivative of the transfer matrix, which gives $L$ charges, if one also includes $S^z$. I have not read the first reference that you cite.)

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/796554/

Comment: Did the above help?